# React: TypeError for split : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, split

I am trying to fetch data via apı and  I kinda did it. However, I have problem wwith split. I tried everything but I got still this error. How can I Achive that?

edit: I installed this **$npm add react-split**
and import it like so : *import Split from 'react-split'.*
This is the usage of it in a code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 class PokemonDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    name: '',
    imgUrl: '',
    pokemonIndex: '',
    
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
    const {name, url} = this.props;
    const pokemonIndex = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 2];
    const imageUrl = `https://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites/blob/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}.png?raw=true`;
    
    this.setState ({
       name: name,
       imageUrl: imageUrl,
       pokemonIndex: pokemonIndex 
    });
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: that means that the variable `url` is undefined

Comment: didn' I define it like so:  const {name, url} = this.props;

Comment: if you `console.log` `this.props` you will see that there is no `url `

Comment: how should I define it? I am new in react

Comment: In where this component called ? The parent must send the `name` and `url` as `props`

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by inserting question mark before split. I do not know the reason but it worked.

```
        const pokemonIndex = url?.split('/')[url?.split('/').length - 2];
```

Thanks all who responded my post.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the parent component that call this `PokemonDetail` send the props with the same name.

Like this

```
class Pockemon extend Component {

render(){
   return (
     <>
       <PokemonDetail
          name='Pockemon name' // this line 
          url='the url' // and this line
       />

     </>
   )
}

}
```