# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'split' in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm working on a react project and can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error.

No error was coming from my code. Can anyone help me fix this? Will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please provide more details. (piece of code)

Comment: add your code to get more clarity

Comment: Please share your code - otherwise we can't help you. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/erros when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: TypeError for split : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532251/react-typeerror-for-split-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-split)

Comment: As per the error, you are trying to split the string variable which is not defined/unavailable. Hence, please debug to check if that contains value or not.